# Spacing Between Column Boxes?

Tags: css, sass

I want to put spacing between [these columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Ml2.png), and in the image I've circled the spots with a red pen.

Here's my code:

```css
.help-icons {
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 4rem;

        & > div {
            height: 5rem;
            width: 10rem;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
    }
```

```html
.help-icons
        .icon-one
            span.wfs-pie-chart
            p.dark-text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            p.light-text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        .icon-two
            span.wfs-user
            p.dark-text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            p.light-text Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque.
        .icon-three
            span.wfs-git-branch
            p.dark-text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            p.light-text Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam.
        .icon-four
            span.wfs-database
            p.dark-text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            p.light-text Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum.
        .icon-five
            span.wfs-trending-up
            p.dark-text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            p.light-text Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in.
        .icon-six
            span.wfs-cloud
            p.dark-text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            p.light-text Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet.
```

I'm using Pug instead of HTML and Sass instead of CSS.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here's an image of [what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRgyK.png).

Comment: *"Some spacing"* can be interpreted in multiple ways. Be as specific as possible. Also note your [mcve] is quite far from displaying the issue you're describing. Make sure it is **verifiable**. Even if you write Pug, you can still copy-paste the resulting markup from "right-click > view page source" to make sure the snippet displays your problem here (so any potential answers can be tested).

Comment: Yes. You need to parse your pug into html and use that on SO if you want people to be able to test their answers.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might need to put some padding on
    & > div {

Comment: My apologies for not asking what you were trying to do. I'm still not sure really. Are you trying to make the top and bottom boxes separate? If so, would margin-bottom on '& > div {' work?

Comment: @tdrsam yes, I'm trying to make the top and bottom boxes separate. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starter:

```scss
.help-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  > div {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    > span {
      width: 4rem;
      height: 4rem;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 2rem;
      color: white;
      font-size: 2.4rem;
    }
    .dark-text {
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
  }
}
```

Most importantly, **don't use `float` for that layout** or your boxes will start jumping around the moment they have different heights.